# Rails 3.1 + Mailer + Delayed_jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, delayed-job

I kept getting this error when I use delayed_job + Rails 3.1 + ActionMailer

> Notifier.delay({:run_at => 1.minutes.from_now}).test_email

Error:

> Class#test_email failed with NoMethodError: undefined method `test_email' for Class:Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug with the most recent version of delayed_job. You can read more about how to fix it here: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/323#issuecomment-3496647